# Counting number of words which starts with 'A' letter? - C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, count

I just started learning C after Java, so it's a little bit confusing to me. I tried to write a program with idea of counting the numbers of words which start with 'A' letter. The problem is that it only reads the first word I enter and ignore the rest of the sentence. Can somebody help me with this one? I would appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {

    char sentence[200];
    int i;
    int counter = 0;
    printf("Enter sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", &sentence);

    for (i = 0; sentence[i] != 0, sentence[i] != ' '; i++){
            if (sentence[i] == 'A') {
                counter = counter +1;
            }
        }
        printf("No. of A in string %s > %d\n", sentence, counter);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to shows minimal research effort.

Comment: I'm beginner, didn't know it's a crime to ask. People are so rude sometimes. At least I'm willing to learn from people who knows better than me and from my mistakes.

Comment: @CruelWorld You can start with how to read strings in C, then read strings with spaces (sentence). Then how to use tokenizer in C etc.

Comment: @CruelWorld it's not a crime to ask, but string splitting in C has been covered _ad nauseam_ on this site (and _dozens_ of others!). Duplicate questions are strongly discouraged, and a minimum amount of research is essentially required here.

Comment: @SatishKumar Yeah, I'll have to. I need to get used to work in C.

Comment: Since you already know Java, the obvious thing to do is get it working in Java first.  Given that, what are you expecting of `sentence[i] != 0, sentence[i] != ' '`?

Comment: @Jules It's preferable to close as dupe than lack of minimal effort, I think.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo fair point, gotta get back into review queue best practices.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Scan with `strstr` the string for words starting with "A" after empty space, then for the first word in the string:

```
...
fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);

int count = 0;
const char *tmp = sentence;

while(tmp = strstr(tmp, " A")) {
   count++;
   tmp++;
}

if (sentence[0] == 'A') count++;

...
```

Comment: You forgot to take input.

Comment: because it's obvious

Comment: I got it. Thank you guys for your help and thank you for not being mean like some person above.

Comment: Taking input is not obvious to OP. He misused `scanf("%s",...)` for strings with white space.

Comment: fair enough, I've added it

Answer (score 0):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 200 };
    char sentence[N];

    printf( "Enter sentence: " );
    fgets( sentence, N, stdin );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = sentence; *p; p += strcspn( p,  " \t" ) )
    {
        p += strspn( p, " \t" );
        if ( *p == 'A' ) ++n;
    }

    printf("No. of A in string \"%s\" is %zu\n", sentence, n );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter sentence: Any word that starts with A
No. of A in string "Any word that starts with A" is 2
```

Also it is better to substitute the string literal `" \t"` for a named variable.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 200 };
    char sentence[N];
    char c = 'A';

    const char *blank = " \t";

    printf( "Enter sentence: " );
    fgets( sentence, N, stdin );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = sentence; *p; p += strcspn( p,  blank ) )
    {
        p += strspn( p, blank );
        if ( *p == c ) ++n;
    }

    printf("No. of %c in string \"%s\" is %zu\n", c, sentence, n );

    return 0;
}
```

You could write a separate function that does the task. The function declaration will look like

```
size_t count_words_start_with( const char *s, char c );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 size_t count_words_start_with( const char *s, char c )
 {
    const char *blank = " \t";
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s; *p; p += strcspn( p,  blank ) )
    {
        p += strspn( p, blank );
        if ( *p == c ) ++n;
    }

    return n;
 }

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 200 };
    char sentence[N];
    char c = 'A';

    printf( "Enter sentence: " );
    fgets( sentence, N, stdin );


    printf("No. of %c in string \"%s\" is %zu\n", 
        c, sentence, count_words_start_with( sentence, c ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that my answers almost always are the best answers.:)